# Форма отправки изображений вложенных в письмо? как сделать mail.php

Tags: php, email, form, img

Пытаюсь собрать mail.php так, что бы он отправлял изображение вложенное в письмо HTML (не прикрепленное, а именно вложенное) с ссылкой на страницу сайта. Что-то вроде E-card должно получиться, отправка через форму фото-открыток. Сейчас остановился на таком... если у кого есть идеи пишите.

```html
   <?php
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
if($post) {
 $photo = $_POST['photo']; /// ссылка на изображение
 $url = $_POST['url']; /// ссылка на страницу
 $address = $_POST['address'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
        $error = '';
 if(!$address) {$error .= 'Укажите электронную почту. ';}
 if(!$message || strlen($message) < 1) {$error .= 'Введите сообщение. ';}
 if(!$error) {
 $email = $_POST['email']; 
                $email = "email@Photo-card.com";
                $sub = "Theme photo-card";
  $mes = "Тема: " .$sub."\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\n";
  $send = mail ($address,$sub,$mes,"Content-type:text/plain; charset = UTF-8\r\nFrom:$email");
  if($send) {echo 'OK';}
 }
 else {echo '<div class="err">'.$error.'</div>';}
}
?>
```

Comment: почитать как минимум документацию

Comment: нет смысла вникать в то, что нужно один раз )))) наверное проще спросить тут

Comment: Проще поставить задачу фрилансеру. Дух этого сообщества не попросить готовое решение, или решить за себя. А углубить свои знания в программирование, найти лучшее решение, узнать новое... Сдесь люди отвечая не зарабатывают репутацию, а закрепляют свои знания, а люди которые задают вопросы они учатся. Сдесь то место где разражаеться полемика и споры о том какое решение лучше, здесь рождается истина. Это сообщество не "бесплатный фриланс" ибо есть хорошая Русская поговорка "без труда не вытащишь и рыбку из пруда"

Comment: не кто и не спорит

Comment: Могу лиш посоветовать покапать в сторону `header` в частности `Content-type` и как отправить письмо в html формате.

Comment: да так оно и есть, использовал значение "HTML" в Content-type:text/html и $mes = "<html><body><h2>Фото-открытка</h2><hr noshade><img src=".$photo."><br><small><a href=".$url.">Посмотреть фотографию на сайте</a></small><br><br>".$message."<br><hr noshade></body></html>"; вроде бы все заработало ... но буду исследовать дальше полезности для отображения письма ))))

Comment: Хорошо, а как возникнут вопросы конкретно по коду можете писать сдесь